# SqlConnection ExecuteAsync hangs on Linux but not on Windows

Tags: linux, freeze, masstransit, sqlcommand

ASP.Net Core

I have the code than calls 
`var resp = await conn.ExecuteAsync("procedureName", sqlParams, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure).ConfigureAwait(false)`

When I start my application on my Windows machine - everything is working fine. But when I deploy it on linux the execution hangs on executing this `ExecuteAsync` method.
This happens when I call my code from Masstransit consumer, and occurres not every request.
Why there is different

Comment: Please show the relevant code and state the exact problem or error. A description alone is not enough. Also see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Are you running application referencing same database environment?